# How can I recover a saved version of a document, that was not checked in?

Tags: word, check-in

I'm in a bit of an odd situation.

I had a Word document checked out for editing, in Word 2007.  I made a bunch of changes, and clicked the Save button in Word.  But, I forgot to actually check the document back in.  Now, when I go to check the document out from Sharepoint, I don't see any of my changes and I'm alerted that the copy I've downloaded may not be the latest.

Since I specifically recall hitting the Save button in Word, I'm fairly certain that the updated document *must* exist somewhere, most likely on my computer.  How do I access that copy, so that I can check it in?

Is this possible, or do I just have to re-do all of my changes?  Fortunately, re-doing the changes isn't impossible in this case - it's just a bit inconvenient.

I'm not sure what version of Sharepoint our organization is using.

**UPDATE:**  I was luckily able to find the modified copy in my "Recent Documents" history in Word.  However, I would like to know if there's another more reliable way since it is possible for this list to get over-written or disabled.  Additionally, this copy of the document no longer appears to be linked to Sharepoint - I cannot simply check it in from Word, and will have to manually upload it to Sharepoint and tell it to overwrite the existing document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents checked out to the Local drafts folder (this is the default) are stored in the "My Documents\SharePoint Drafts" folder

Comment: Thanks.  That's good to be aware of.  However, it seems these documents, once closed, are no longer associated with Sharepoint.  In order to post my changes, I have to discard the check-out, and manually upload the document as a new version.  Is there a way to recover the document, which will allow me to just simply check it in with the saved changes?

Comment: Usually they should keep the connection to SharePoint, so that if you open them from the folder you can check them in directly and if you click the document in SharePoint it opens from that folder. But as any IT this break sometimes.